# action Listener event of w3c dom in webview

Tags: java, dom, webview

I am trying to handle click event on button using w3c.dom.events in java but i am getting error of "cannot make static refrence to a not-static method addEventListener" please help me out.Here is my code.

```
 Node button = form.getElementsByTagName("button").item(0);
                            if(button!=null && button.hasAttributes()){
                                NamedNodeMap attr = button.getAttributes();
                                for(int j=0; j<attr.getLength(); j++){
                                    Attr atribute = (Attr)attr.item(j);
                                    if(atribute.getValue().equals("submit")){
                                        System.out.println("submit button detected.");
                                        org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener listener = new org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener(){
                                            @Override
                                            public void handleEvent(org.w3c.dom.events.Event evt) {
                                                System.out.println("this is a action listener.");
                                            }

                                        };
                                        ((EventTarget) button)org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget.addEventListener("click", listener, false); //here i am getting the error

                                    }

                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving "cannot make static reference to a not-static method addEventListener" means:
The method: `addEventListener` is not a static method -- this means you cannot call it from its class directly, you would need to create an object which implements 'EventTarget' to call it.

```
((EventTarget) button)org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget.addEventListener("click", listener, false);
```

So if we break down this line of code we have: a type cast on the object called 'button': `(EventTarget)button`, followed by ANOTHER type cast onto whatever the  method call `addEventListener` returns (void). So basically what the computer sees is that you called the method `addEventListener` inside the `EventTarget` interface(which is not possible thus the error since the method is NOT STATIC you CANNOT call it DIRECTLY from the Class/Interface) and you are type casting it to type `EventTarget`.
ALSO NOTE: Static methods in interfaces cannot exist.

To fix this just use your button object you created to add the `Eventlistener`:

```
((EventTarget)button).addEventListener("click", listener, false);
```

So in this case you are typecasting the button to an EventTarget. Notice the `.`, which will allow you now to add the Event Listener to the object (button).

Comment: there was a problem with some imports and i solved thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in imports. Here is my solved and modified code.

```
`public class DetectForm {
    private HTMLInputElement password = null;
    private HTMLInputElement username = null;
    private boolean isForm = false;
    public void detect(Document doc){


        if (doc!=null && doc.getElementsByTagName("form").getLength() > 0) {
            HTMLFormElement form = (HTMLFormElement) doc.getElementsByTagName("form").item(0);
            NodeList nodes = form.getElementsByTagName("input");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                if(nodes.item(i).hasAttributes()){
                    NamedNodeMap attr = nodes.item(i).getAttributes();
                    for (int j=0 ; j<attr.getLength();j++){
                        Attr atribute = (Attr)attr.item(j);
                        if(atribute.getValue().equals("password")){
                            System.out.println("Password detected");
                            password = (HTMLInputElement) nodes.item(i);
                            username = (HTMLInputElement) nodes.item(i-1);
                            //                          password.setValue("helloword");
                            //                          username.setValue("helloword");
                            isForm = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            EventListener listener = new EventListener() {
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(Event evt) {
                    System.out.println("action listener from DOM.");
                    if(username!=null && password!=null){
                        String user = username.getValue();
                        String pass = password.getValue();
                    }


                }
            };
            if(isForm){
                Node button = form.getElementsByTagName("button").item(0);
                if(button!=null && button.hasAttributes()){
                    NamedNodeMap attr = button.getAttributes();
                    for(int j=0; j<attr.getLength(); j++){
                        Attr atribute = (Attr)attr.item(j);
                        if(atribute.getValue().equals("submit")){
                            System.out.println("submit button detected.");
                            ((EventTarget) button).addEventListener("click", listener, false);

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }




    }

}
`
```